# Lower audio output volume on audio input (speech)

Tags: audio-recording, windows

What would be the prefered way to lower the volume of my audio output whenever I speak?

Similar thing is being done on some radio stations with some continuos music playing in the background. I'm guessing they're doing it manually, but I'd like to scale the volume of output inversely to the volume of input automatically.

I'm going to be using this for livestreaming, so the channel doesn't sound too empty when I'm not speaking.

Please suggest a solution for both Windows and Linux (feel free to get techy on this one, I'm a fairly proficient power user).

*I'm not certain this is the correct stack exchange site for this question, so feel free to redirect me*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that whith some dynamic Compressor audio plug-in. We name this technic "ducking". When You are speaking, the signal of your voice triggers the compressor which (correctly set) lower the level of the music.

I don't know stand alone plug-in which works on Windows, but that surely exist.

Clem

Comment: In complement, look for an 'external key' parameter in a compressor plugin.

Comment: Oh yeah, I used that when I had an opportunity to play with FL studio. But is there anything you could suggest me to use on the system itself? As I said it's used for live streaming.

Comment: I lost you at "through almost host program". What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Oops, I can understand that - posted from my phone - that went well :-S 
What I meant is that you can do "live" streaming through almost any host program that supports live audio input monitoring, VST plugins and side chaining. Reaper is one cheap way to do it - but there are certainly simpler apps for this too.

Comment: Allright, I seem to have found what I've needed.
https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/degaths-ducker.251/
Since I'm using it for streaming, this seems perfect.